# Mac: MediaKit reports no such partition (dual boot with linux)

Tags: linux, mac, partitioning, multi-boot, osx-mavericks

I am trying to update to OSX Maverick on my Mac, but i cant install it since it says "Disk cannot be used to start the computer", when i choose Machintosh HD as installation disk. I searched around a bit and it seems that resizing the Machintosh HD partition would fix this problem, but when i try that it gives me the error "MediaKit reports no such partition". I'm assuming this has something to do with me dual booting OSX and Ubuntu. I have tried to resize it with iPartition, but that doesn't work either. I hope some of you folks can help me with this matter!

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 625142448s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start       End         Size        File system     Name                  Flags
 1      40s         409639s     409600s     fat32           EFI system partition  boot
 2      409640s     546755263s  546345624s  hfs+            Customer
 3      546756608s  616933375s  70176768s   ext4
 4      616933376s  625141759s  8208384s    linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Please boot to linux and type `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print`. Edit your question to include the output of that command.

Comment: Done.  Can you see whats wrong?